# Want to implement delay in scroll to scroll smoothly in Scrolltohorizontal offset method

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7.1

I need to scroll smoothly when scrolltohorizontal offset value sets. From 1000 offset, if i scroll to 5000, it suddenly moves with a blink and fix the view in 5000. I need to scroll slow and smooth like animation and have to reach the destination. Without using the story board how can I achieve that?

Comment: How do you intend to have an animation without a storyboard?

Comment: is animation must to acheive this? Isn't any time delay functions to set the duration for scroll to horizontal offset.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that without implementing the storyboard animation we cant acheive the smooth scroll. I refer this class and got the result.

http://blog.devarchive.net/